# Implicits Confusion

Tags: scala, spire

The following polymorphic methods compile:

```
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._

scala> def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2 * d
foo: [A](d: A)(implicit evidence$1: spire.math.Numeric[A])A

scala> def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2 + d
foo: [A](d: A)(implicit evidence$1: spire.math.Numeric[A])A
```

However, if I change the integer `2` to the double `2.0` the compiler complains about not finding an implicit value

```
scala> def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2.0 + d
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: spire.algebra.Field[A]
       def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2.0 + d
                                       ^

scala> def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2.0 * d
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: spire.algebra.Field[A]
       def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2.0 * d
                                       ^
```

I have tried to understand some of the other questions and answers on SO but I am none the wiser on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I find the clearest way to see what's going on with implicits is to use `reify` (your IDE may provide similar functionality):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> reify { def foo[A:Numeric](d : A) = 2 * d }
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] =
Expr[Unit]({
  def foo[A](d: A)(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[A]) = implicits.literalIntMultiplicativeSemigroupOps(2).$times(d)(evidence$1);
  ()
})
```

And looking in the spire source we see:

```
final class LiteralIntMultiplicativeSemigroupOps(val lhs: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def *[A](rhs:A)(implicit ev: Ring[A]): A = ev.times(ev.fromInt(lhs), rhs)
}
```

This is an implicit class that makes a `*` method available on `Int`s, provided the value on the right (`d` in your code) is some `A` which forms a `Ring` (which any `Numeric` `A` will). So your first example works. But in the second example there's no such implicit (no `LiteralDoubleMultiplicativeSemigroupOps` or the like), so the second example doesn't compile.

Comment: There is this implicit : `LiteralDoubleMultiplicativeSemigroupOps` but it is not getting applied.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from lmm:

to add or multiply something of type T to an integer, spire requires just the [spire.algebra.Ring[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Ring.scala) typeclass, which [spire.algebra.Numeric[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/math/Numeric.scala) extends.

See for example LiteralIntAdditiveSemigroupOps in [spire.syntax.Ops](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/syntax/Ops.scala)

to add or multiply something of type T to a double, spire requires an instance of the [spire.algebra.Field[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Field.scala) typeclass, which [spire.algebra.Numeric[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/math/Numeric.scala) does ***not*** extend.

See for example LiteralDoubleAdditiveSemigroupOps in [spire.syntax.Ops](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/syntax/Ops.scala)

#### The reason for this design decision:

The result of e.g. adding an Int to a T has to be T. So you need a way to convert an Int to T. This is available for [spire.algebra.Ring[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Ring.scala) (the fromInt method). To convert an integer n to T, just use the *one* element of T and sum it n times using the *+* operation of T.

The result of e.g. adding a Double to a T has also to be T. But for that you need a way to convert a ***Double*** to a T, which is much more complex and is only available in [spire.algebra.Field[T]](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Field.scala) (the fromDouble method). Take a look at the generic fromDouble method in Field. It is some pretty complex code that makes use of the ***div*** operation of Field[T], which of course does not exist on Ring[T].

#### How to modify your code

If you really want to multiply with a double for whatever reason, you have to modify the method like this:

```
def foo[A: Field](d: A) = 2.0 * d
```